# How can I find the equation of a transformed function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, transformation

For example, if I have a function $f(x) = x^2 + 4x + 1$ and I am transforming it using an equation like $p(x) = 2f(x + 1) - 5$, how would I find the equation of p(x)? I understand the rules of transformation, but do not understand how to apply these to finding transformations of equations. Using Photomath, I get that $p(x) = 2x^2 + 12x + 7$, but I don’t understand why this is.

Comment: If $f(x) = x^2 + 4x + 1$, what is $f(x+1)$? If you're not sure, think about what $f(0)$ or $f(1)$ is, and follow the same strategy. From there, computing $p(x)$ should be pretty straightforward.

Also, have a look here to learn how to format your equations properly https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference.

Comment: You can call it a case of composing substitutions, if you like. First, $x$ is replaced with $x+1$ in the equation for $f(x)$; the result is $f(x+1)$, and this is substituted for $f(x+1)$ in the equation for $p(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$p(x) = 2f(x+1) - 5$

Let's say for a moment that $u = x+1.$  This step is not really necessary, but it might help make the details a little more clear.

$p(x) = 2f(u) - 5$

Put in what we know for $f(u)$

$p(x) = 2(u^2 + 4u+1) - 5$

Reverse the substitution.

$p(x) = 2((x+1)^2 + 4(x+1) + 1) - 5.$  If you were to have jumped to this place, that would be fine.

Multiply out what we have and simplify.

$p(x) = 2(x^2 + 2x +1 + 4x+4 + 1) - 5\\
2(x^2 + 6x +6) - 5\\
2x^2 + 12x +12 - 5\\
2x^2 + 12x +7$

Comment: Thank you so much!